# How do I import JIMP into Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Angular/Typescript novice here.

I am trying to bring [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/jimp)into my Ionic project.

I've followed the Github documentation to `npm install --save jimp` and `import Jimp from 'jimp/es';`

I'm stuck now, with the application throwing a `StaticInjectorError`.

Basically, how do I import Jimp properly? I'm stuck and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks for reading!

Edit:

in the past, I am used to being able to import modules into my `app.module.ts` and respective pages that use the modules in the constructor, but Jimp seems to be a different case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jimp exposes definition file(.d.ts) in root of the project. So

**App.Module.ts**

```
import Jimp from 'jimp';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ Jimp ],
```

**Component:**

```
import Jimp from 'jimp';
Jimp.read('');
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bx1aae